# Is Mt.Gox currently accepting Dwolla deposits or withdrawals?

Tags: mtgox, dwolla

I know that [Dwolla stopped depositing/withdrawing funds in Mt.Gox due to a court order](http://www.btcpedia.com/dwolla-halts-mtgox-trading/), but does anyone know if this is still in place?

#### Related

[Why can't Dwolla send to Mt Gox?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10924/why-cant-dwolla-send-to-mt-gox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of this writing, Dwolla is not sending money to MtGox

This is verified by accessing [their deposit link here](https://www.dwolla.com/hub/812-649-1010?)

Comment: That link doesn't say mtgox is not accepting money from Dwolla; it says Dwolla is not sending money to mtgox.